# Will checking the backup voltage on an RTC drain it's backup battery?

Tags: batteries, avr, analog, atmega

I'm working on an ATMega project that will be keeping time and I'm trying to make it so you have an option of either software time (millis() based), DS1307, or DS3231 (ChronoDot) RTCs.

At the most basic, what I would like to do is have headers for a ChronoDot available to solder in and then somehow in software detect if the ChronoDot is attached and switch to using that. It would typically be easy enough to check that either the DS1307 or DS3231 is present as they use the same I2C register, but after that initial check they do deviate from one another a little and the latter has more features. So I still want to determine which is connected. In general, I plan on having a place directly on board to solder in the DS1307 as the default option and the DS3231 support would be with a complete ChronoDot only via dual 4 pin headers. The ChronoDot would essentially fit over the place where the DS1307 would normally go (it would not be populated in this case). The main reason I'm focusing on the ChronoDot specifically is that it's popular, easy to acquire and doesn't require SMD soldering for the end user (this if for a kit). So, here's what I'm thinking...

The both the DS1307 and DS3231 have a Vbat line on the chip, but it's not really needed for anything. However, the ChronoDot has an actual VBat pin on the breakout board. I could maybe hookup only Vbat from the ChronoDot header and not the DS1307 and connect it to a digital input pin on my ATMega. But have that input pin pulled down to ground by a resistor (not really sure what value... maybe 4.7k?). If my EE theory is correct I can then read that pin and if I get a low, there's no chronodot but if I get a high, there is.

Something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frshPS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My main question here is if doing this will just end up draining the backup battery on the RTC? Normally there would be no current drawn from the backup battery while main, 5V, power is supplied but would hooking this up to a digital input make it draw power from the battery all the time? Or, is there a mode I would need to put the pin into after reading from it in order to "disconnect" it, so to speak? I know I could change it to output, but I believe that if it's set as output and low I would basically be grounding the battery.

Anyways, my EE courses were a *long* time ago. Any help on the theory here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

You will certainly drain the battery through the resistor. The amount of current you will draw will be governed by Ohm's law: I = V / R. Lets say your battery voltage is 3V (i.e. the usual chronodot Vbat). With a 4.7 kOhm resistor you will draw 3/4700 = 638 microamps continuously. If you make that a 1 MOhm resistor, you will instead draw 3/1000000 = 3 microamps. And If you make that a 10 MOhm resistor, you will instead draw 3 / 1e7 = 300 nanoamps.

The bigger the value resistor your choose, the less current you will draw continuously, but the longer it will take for your digital pin to transition (think R*C time constant governed by resistance and the capacitance of the pins and traces). So long as you wait long enough (or check back periodically) after startup, you should be OK with a 10 MOhm resistor. Theoretically, you could pick up more noise with a larger value as well (as it starts to look more and more like an open circuit), but I think you'll be fine. I might even consider going up to 100 MOhm.

A typical CR1632 has 130 milliamp-hours (mAh) of energy stored in it, and maybe 80% of that is useful life, so lets just call it 100 mAh for ease of calculation. A coarse estimate of your battery life is then milliamp-hours / milliamps draw.

- With your 4.7 kOhm resistor that's 100 / .638 = 156 hours = 6.5 days
- With a 1 MOhm resistor that's 100 / 0.003 = 33333 hours = 3.8 years
- With a 10 MOhm resistor that's 100 / 0.0003 = 333333 hours = 38 years

These are upper bound numbers that assume the rest of your system draws no power. They represent the lifetime of your system when it is off and the battery is simply drained through the resistance. There are also lots of second order effects that are not taken into account (voltage decay, internal battery leakage chemistry, etc). The resistor is unlikely to be your biggest problem depending on the lifetime you are hoping to achieve.

Comment: Duh... can't believe I neglected to notice the fact that I was grounding the battery directly :P

Any suggestions on a different way to do this?

Comment: I think your approach is fine, given a large enough resistor the leakage current won't significantly impact your battery life, I'll update with some more math.

Comment: Upvote: Answering the main question.

@AdamHaile a technique you may find useful: digital voltmeters uses a FET that presents an insignificant drain equivalent of a resistor in orders or MOhms.

Comment: @AdamHaile one quick thing... I noticed your comment that your system is a 5V in another comment. Watch out that your digital Voltage Input High threshold is high enough to register with a drained battery (probably down to about 2V for a CR1632) - check your microcontroller's datasheet

Answer (score 2):

The DS3231 has internal temperature that you can read.  You could issue a command over I2C to read the temperature, if you got a response you have the DS3231, if not you have the DS1307.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question in any way.

Comment: I think it does.  Adam in the OP wants to determine if a DS3231 or DS1307 is connected to his circuit.  He was thinking of trying to do this with the vbat pin.  I'm suggesting he do it by seeing if the device will return the temperature.  Seems to me like it should work just fine.

Comment: I think this does address the question: Not the question that was asked, but the underlying problem statement. Interesting.  It would get my upvote if fleshed out a bit, and with references added.

Comment: In the [Maxim data sheet](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS3231.pdf) see Figure 1 on page 11.  It shows the registers (11 & 12) for the internal temperature.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much any of these measuring schemes involving resistors, if left permanently connected, will cause unacceptable current draw and life reduction of the small lithium battery that powers these devices.

The solution then, is to only have the measuring circuit draw current during briefly at infrequent intervals, when you are actually taking a measurement.

For a digital test, this could be as easy as using an internal, software configurable pulldown, and only configuring it as a pulldown for a brief period of time surrounding the test.  However, you will need to look into possible complications of having voltage on the pin when the MCU doing the measurement is not powered/in sleep mode.

An analog measurement would get trickier, but similar ideas could be applied.  For example, you could connect the lower resistor of a (high impedance relative to the I/Os) voltage divider to an output pin, and only drive it low for a time surrounding the measurement.  Or you might even be able to build an RC circuit with a small low-leakage capacitor and a single I/O pin which you could drive low as an output, then configure as an analog input and measure the voltage after some period of time.  If the device's digital threshold voltage is consistent (watch out for temperature!) you can even do make an analog measurement with a digital input this way, by measuring the time it takes for the capacitor to charge to the threshold voltage.

Comment: Hmmm... I wish I could do the internal pull-down thing, but sadly there is only internal pull-up resistors.
I may be trying to overcomplicate things. A solder pad that has to be bridged to use one mode or the other would probably be acceptable.

Comment: You could make your own software-configurable pulldown with a resistor to another I/O pin.  Or you can use the RC circuit circuit idea, driving the same pin you will then reconfigure as an input to measure.

Comment: Actually, using an internal pull-down is a very bad idea.  I/O pins are generally connected to Vdd and GND with diodes to prevent the pin voltage from straying outside of the supply voltage.  When the chip is not powered, the pin will basically be tied to GND with two parallel diodes and applying any voltage over the threshold voltage of the diodes will result in a very large current flow.  A better idea would be to use a series PMOS transistor whose gate is controlled by an NMOS transistor to ground.  This will minimize leakage when the microcontroller is not powered.